# Deep Q-Learning Agent performance degrades after a certain number of epochs

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have a DQN agent which is trained on a specific network to perform a task. However, when training the agent I noticed that after an initial number of epochs where the agent shows a general growth in the score of the task, there suddenly occurs a drastic decrease in the performance of the agent as if it is starting out afresh. This happens a number of times.

**My agent shows fluctuations in performance from bad to good and so on.** Is this normal for DQN agents. What diagnosis should I perform to enable remove such fluctuations? I have used experience replay and exploration-exploitation for the agent. I am relatively new to the field so the question may be pretty trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These fluctuations are normal until it reach at optimal level. In most of the reinforcement experiments and papers, results are shown by weighted average with `window size of 15-30`. Here is graph of my`dqn`implementation.

[image]